# Unable to find webadmin in plesk 12.x?

Tags: plesk

I'm trying to import sql database in plesk.So i have created a database and a database user.Now I want to import database but I'm unable to find tools and webadmin.I have gone through all the instructions available through google search but every problem is related to some other version.What is the other way around to import sql database in plesk?
Here is the image of my panel
[image]

Comment: It means that phpMyadmin not installed on server or plesk's admin hide it from GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install PHPMyAdmin to upload database via Plesk 12. In next version Plesk 12.1 there will be a new database tab with lots of database options, including uploading new database, downloading database, repair also changing ownership. 12.1 should be out late September.